# How to deploy a private docker hub image to an Azure Logic App using the 'Create container group' action

Tags: azure, docker, azure-logic-apps, dockerhub

First time creating an image on Docker Hub and trying to deploy it to Azure. I am trying to schedule a private docker hub container to run daily using an Azure Logic App, similar to something like this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aci-logicapps-integration

Given, that I am deploying a private image, I have added the additional parameter: `imageRegistryCredentials` which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "password": "<The password for the private registry>",
    "server": "<The Docker image registry server without a protocol such as 'myacr.azurecr.io'>",
    "username": "<The username for the private registry>"
  }
]
```

I have looked at multiple other posts about docker registry urls and have tried to input values for the "server" credential such as:

```
- registry.hub.docker.com/username/repo
- registry.hub.docker.com/username/repo:tag
- index.docker.io/v1/
- docker.io/library/repo:tag
```

However they all throw the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidImageRegistryServer",
    "message": "The server '<server>' in the 'imageRegistryCredentials' of container group '<container group>' is invalid. It should be a valid host name without protocol."
  }
}
```

What is the correct format to provide for the 'server' credential?

Comment: You can try `https://index.docker.io/v1/`, just like you use it when you log in.

Comment: This still returns the same `InvalidImageRegistryServer` error

Comment: What about `index.docker.io`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server in the `imageRegistryCredentials` should be `index.docker.io`, just like the server when you use the ACR. And you can also take a look at [the solution in Private docker hub image example](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9799#issuecomment-397389055).