# How to deploy To Azure App Service WebSite from Docker Hub using Bicep

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, dockerhub

**Summary:**

I have made many attempts to deploy simple C# Blazor image in public DockerHub repo to Azure App Service web site. All attempts using bicep and the azure portal have failed.

**Goal:**

Use bicep inside of a Github action (CI/CD pipeline) to deploy from public DockerHub repo to Azure App Service Web Site. (I'm also curious as to how to do it on the portal).

**What Works:**

1. This powershell command successfully deploys my DockerHub image to the Azure App Service Web site:

`az.cmd webapp create  --name DockerhubDeployDemo004  --resource-group  rg_  --plan Basic-ASP -s siegfried01 -w topsecretet --deployment-container-image-name siegfried01/demovisualstudiocicdforblazorserver`

2. [This bicep for creating an azure container instance also works.](https://github.com/siegfried01/DemoVisualStudioCICDForBlazorServer001/blob/main/DemoVisualStudioCICDForBlazorServer/deploy-DemoVisualStudioCICDForBlazorServer.bicep#L109)

**Error Messages from Failed Attempts:**

From the log files in the azure portal I get:

```
2022-05-20T21:50:35.914Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for demovisualstudiocicdforblazorserver, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}
2022-05-20T21:50:35.915Z ERROR - Pulling docker image docker.io/demovisualstudiocicdforblazorserver failed:
2022-05-20T21:50:35.916Z WARN  - Image pull failed. Defaulting to local copy if present.
2022-05-20T21:50:35.923Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2022-05-20T21:50:35.928Z INFO  - Stopping site dockerdeploydemo003 because it failed during startup.
/home/LogFiles/2022_05_20_lw1sdlwk000FX5_docker.log  (https://dockerdeploydemo003.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2022_05_20_lw1sdlwk000FX5_docker.log)
2022-05-20T21:35:47.559Z WARN  - Image pull failed. Defaulting to local copy if present.
2022-05-20T21:35:47.562Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
```

**Failing Bicep Code:**

[I tried exporting the ARM code from the successful powershell deployment and the failed portal attempts and converting it to bicep. In both cases the code was very similar. In both cases I had to add/edit the app settings containing the dockerhub URL, account and password.](https://github.com/siegfried01/DemoVisualStudioCICDForBlazorServer001/blob/main/DemoVisualStudioCICDForBlazorServer/deploy-FromPrivateDockerhubFailed.bicep#L33) I always received the above error messages. After deploying using bicep code, I could go back into the portal and view the appsettings (dockerhub creds & URL). They looked correct.

**References:**

1. [Nice DockerHub example but no bicep code.. Says to use `index.docker.io` for the server and I tried that (did not work). I also tried using `https://index.docker.io/v1/` for the server URL and that did not work either.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165359/how-to-deploy-a-private-docker-hub-image-to-an-azure-logic-app-using-the-create)
2. [Nice Bicep Example but uses ACR instead of DockerHub](https://github.com/jamiemccrindle/bicep-app-service-container/blob/main/infra/appService/main.bicep#L35)
3. [Another nice Bicep Example that uses ACR instead of DockerHub](https://foldr.uk/azure-bicep-app-service-custom-container/).

I was surprised I could not find the documentation on the DockerHub site!

Please help me correct my bicep code. I suspect I'm not specifying the correct URL or server for DockerHub.

Thanks

Siegfried

Answer (score 2):

1. I could not find the web page on Dockerhub that gave the detailed information I was looking for (like the URL). However, the docker Info command [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198392/docker-official-registry-docker-hub-url) was very helpful.
2. This bicep code did the trick for me (with some help from the bicep support on github):

```
var appConfigNew = {
  DOCKER_ENABLE_CI: 'true'
  DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD: dockerhubPassword
  DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL: 'https://index.docker.io/v1/'
  DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME: dockerUsername
}

resource appSettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-01-15' = {
  name: 'appsettings'
  parent: web
  properties: appConfigNew
}
```

3. And lastly, I discovered this by trial and error:

```
      linuxFxVersion: 'DOCKER|${dockerUsername}/demovisualstudiocicdforblazorserver:${tag}'
```

Wow! I really worked hard for this one!